# Pun of the word “fall”

Tags: puns, polysemes

Is this sentence sound native to English speakers?

> Fall falls on falls.

Which I intended to say "Autumn comes to the waterfalls."

If this does not sound native, how would you use the word "fall" to make jokes like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's falls flat, but so do most of my puns.

Comment: It sounds excessively contrived to me.

Comment: You would need a context.  As a title to, say, a photographic article about the foliage and the falls, it would work.  In itself, it sounds odd and probably too hard to decipher.

Comment: It reads like a newspaper headline or photo caption - each of which have enough accompanying context for it to make sense. In isolation it seems more like a simple riddle.

Comment: I think using "falls" for waterfalls isn't very common and would only make sense in context. It's not the most obvious meaning of falls for most people, who seldom encounter waterfalls or think about them. "The falls" would be slightly clearer as it would be more likely to refer to a place and less likely to refer to people falling over.

Comment: *using "falls" for waterfalls isn't very common* well, other than at the Niagara Falls, the Victoria Falls, and one or many others?

Comment: Using "fall" to mean Autumn sounds contrived and somewhat foreign - I think it's a North American usage.

Comment: There are lots of hills called Mount Something but you wouldn't say "I'm going up a mount". Same with "Falls".

Comment: This mixes up two senses of the verb _fall_. (1) to arrive as if by descending (night/darkness fell) (the curtain metaphor?) // (2) to occur [on a certain day/date] (Easter Sunday falls on the seventeenth this year) (the come to land on metaphor?). (There are many other senses/subsenses.) But 'Autumn fell ...' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I say yes.

My reading of it is that it's a bit poetic, and what I'm imaging is a waterfall with deciduous trees hanging over it, and in autumn the leaves fall off into it.

However, from what you've said:

> Autumn comes to the waterfalls.

This doesn't really make sense in itself, except in the poetic kind of phrasing I mentioned above.

Like - summer, spring and winter also 'come to waterfalls'. It's a fairly meaningless statement by itself, unless that season *has some effect* on the waterfalls.

For example:

> Summer comes to waterfalls and with it, boys jumping off them.

> Winter comes to waterfalls and they freeze over.